# Need to know the name of this toilet wall faucet (thing)

Tags: faucet, washing-machine, taps

I moved to a new place and trying to install the washing machine. The wall faucet for water supply in toilet does not seem to have a handle.

[image]

I cannot find the name of this type of faucet (not even sure if it is a faucet). Lifehacker, IRC, Google/Bing image searches; none of them has yielded anything useful.

Any detail about this [object] would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the "button" on the top push through the bottom? It almost looks like a larger one of [these](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Unbranded-Flow-Control-Shower-On-Off-Push-Button-3075-552/204511124).

Comment: It is a rigid piece of metal. It cannot be pressed and doesn't go through the bottom.